How Out-of-profile DSCP mapping helps to prevent misuse of bandwidth if it can't be remapped to a different queue?
On Cisco SG-300 series and CBS-350 series switches an attempt to configure Out-of-profile DSCP value 46 (EF) to 18 (AF21) causes the following error:

The re-mapped dscp must be mapped to the same queue as the mapped dscp.

In this case, what's the point of Out-of-profile remapping, if the remapped value must belong to the same queue and therefore the exceeding traffic will receive the same treatment as the conforming traffic?
The manual for the CBS-350 switch states in the Out-of-Profile DSCP Remarking:

The device uses the new values to assign resources and the egress queues to these packets.

This statement creates an impression that the new DSCP value can result in the traffic being assigned to a different queue and this idea makes sense to me.
After reading the documentation, I am under the impression that, let's say, if a device is permitted to send 1Mb/s of traffic marked as DSCP 46 (EF), then everything is alright as long as the device does not exceed the rate of 1Mb/s. If for any reason the device begins to send more traffic than 1Mb/s, the excess gets re-mapped with some lower DSCP value and ideally would get assigned to a different low priority queue, thus ensuring that high priority queue usage is not being abused.
But if the re-mapped DSCP value can't belong to a different queue, then what is the point of such re-mapping?
